# Discontinuity of the electric field, vector calculus.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, vector-analysis

I just started a course in vector and multivariable calculus. I'm solving several example to practice but I have some problems with this exercise:

The electric field of a metallic sphere is

\begin{equation}
\textbf{E}(\textbf{r}) = \frac{Q}{4\pi r^2}\frac{1+\frac{r-R}{\left|r-R\right|}}{2}{\textbf{e}_r}
\end{equation}

with $\textbf{r} = (x,y,z) $ and $r = |\textbf{r}| $, $Q$ the charge of the sphere and $R$ the radius. Determine the discontinuity points of this field.

Particularly I studied the situation when $r>R$ and $r<R$:

- If $r > R \rightarrow |r-R| = r-R$ so $\textbf{E}(\textbf{r})=\frac{Q}{4\pi r^2}{\textbf{e}_r}$ which is the expression of the electric field of a point-like particle and I think it has sense because in this case we are outside the sphere.
- if $r < R \rightarrow |r-R| = R-r$ so $\textbf{E}(\textbf{r}) = \textbf{0}$ inside the sphere.

Are then the discontinuity ponits those that rest on the surface of the sphere?. I don't know how to interpret this question about discontinuity.

Comment: What if $r = R$? It's not defined on the sphere, so it can't be discontinuous there.

Comment: So are there some discontinuity point?

Comment: As you say: The electric field inside is zero and outside that of a point charge. See also [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). The discontinuities are obviously the points on the sphere. Not because the field there isn't defined. It is defined but drops to zero when you cross the sphere from outside to inside.